# htaccess redirect any folder to file with parameters in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to add the following rewrite rule to htaccess, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to do it under wordpress.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(data|cache)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ redir.php?redir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My goal is to have any directory under root that doesn't currently exist to redirect to my file redir.php and pass the name of the nonexistent directory as a variable. The above code works, but existing directories are also being passed to the redir.php file as well.

I tried taking a look at the Wordpress Codex for rewrites but everything I've tried adding to functions.php seems to yield no new results, or instead of being sent to redir.php I get a wordpress 404 page.

Any ideas?? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to have any directory under root that doesn't currently exist to redirect to my file `redir.php` ...

You can't do something like this in `.htaccess` with WordPress (or any site that uses a front-controller pattern) since there is no way to determine what is a "directory that does not exist" and a valid WordPress URL, which also does not exist on the filesystem.

If you implement something like this in `.htaccess` then you will essentially override the WordPress site (so none of your WordPress URLs will work).

---

To implement this with WordPress you will need to do it entirely within WordPress (in PHP). Only when you have determined the request does not map to a valid WordPress URL (ie. would otherwise result in a 404) then you could divert the request to your `redir.php` script. (But `.htaccess` executes to early in the request to be able to do that.)

Related question on the [WordPress stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) (closed as being off-topic, probably because it is focusing on the perceived solution (ie. `.htaccess`), rather than the actual problem: Getting WordPress to execute a custom function on a request that would otherwise result in a 404):
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293931/trouble-adding-directory-rewrite-to-htaccess-under-wordpress

Comment: This isn't exactly a "redirect 404s" issue. For example, let's say i have a directory `mydomain.com/thisdirectory` and someone visits `mydomain.com/thisdirectory/blah`, that should show the 404 page, not get sent to redir.php. However, I guess I can code redir.php to handle such requests, so that is what I'm going to try. Thank you!